# Syntax converter from Stata to Lavaan produces \n instead of actual break line

Tags: r, stata, r-lavaan

I would like to create a syntax converted from Stata to the R package Lavaan;

```
stata_to_lavaan <- function(string) {
   string <- gsub("///", "", string)
   string <- gsub("<-", "~", string)
   string <- gsub("->", "~", string)
   string <- gsub("\\(", "", string)
   string <- gsub("\\)", "", string)
   string <- gsub(",", "", string)
   string <- gsub("sem", "", string)
   return(string)
}


stata_to_lavaan("
sem(x1->X, ) (x2<-X,) \\\
(x3<-X) (y<-X,)")
```

produces:

```
"\n    x1~X  x2~X \\\n    x3~X y~X"
```

I would however like to somehow get a text that I can copy paste into R. What are my options to tackle this?

Comment: You could use `cat("\n    x1~X  x2~X \\\n    x3~X y~X") `.

Comment: `lavaan`'s `model=` argument is a character vector, not necessarily a single string. Each parameter can be specified in its own string, collected in a vector.  Perhaps this could simplify the task of your translator.